# Python3 MAAS API

Tags: server, python, maas, oauth

Once again I'm trying to figure out how to query MAAS with python ...

I have the following in the config file ...

```
# /etc/maasinv/maasinv.ini
[maas]
apikey = FbT9S6S9B3U7y38HKZ:NotRealNunyaNunya:randomkeyblahwhatever
url =  http://<valid IP>:5240/MAAS/api/2.0/
```

I have the following in the script ..

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from apiclient import maas_client
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('/etc/maasinv/maasinv.ini')
APIKEY = config['maas']['apikey']
MAAS_URL = config['maas']['url']
auth = maas_client.MAASOAuth(*APIKEY.split(":"))
client = maas_client.MAASClient(auth, maas_client.MAASDispatcher(), MAAS_URL)
data = client.get("nodes", op=list").read()
print (data)
```

The response I get is ...

```
 urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: BAD REQUEST
```

Running a the below curl request gives me `forbidden` which seems to tell me that I'm close:

```
curl http://<valid IP>:5240/MAAS/api/2.0/nodes/op=list/
```

Has anyone gotten this to work or should I go back to using `subprocess` to run the client ?

```
MAAS Version 2.1.3+bzr5573-0ubuntu1 (16.04.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I notice you have a typo in `data = client.get("nodes", op=list").read()` (notice the " after list)

That, however, may be a typo just in here.

If you remove the `,op=list` portion, it should work.

I have the following in a script I run and it works just fine:
`nodes=client.get(u"nodes/?hostname="+hostname).read().decode("utf-8")`